# servlet oracle database connection example

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, netbeans, jdbc

I am using windows 8.1 64 bit OS, oracle 12c database and netbeans ide.i created a java web project named as **WebApplication1** in my netbeans IDE.
in my database I created a user **C##abc** and password **abc** having database SID is **orcl**. In my database I created one table named as **city** with column name **address** and inserted one data 'xyz' to the table city. I run the project and in d browser after writing city in text box I am receiving the message- **Servlet NewServlet at /WebApplication1** but it should display **xyz**. Where i am wrong?

I added 2 jar flies ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc_14.jar files.

My new.jsp

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
<font face="verdana" size="2">
Enter Table Name :<input type="text" name="table"> 
                   <input type="submit" value="Display">
</font>
</form>
```

NewServlet.java

```
package p;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {


/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String tb=request.getParameter("table");     

    try
    {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         Connection
   con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","c##abc","abc");
         Statement st=con.createStatement();
      out.println("connection established successfully...!!");     

         ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from "+tb);


             while(rs.next())
             {
          out.println(rs);              }

    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
       out.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Are both servers (netbeans and oracle) residing on the same box?

Comment: same box?? i did not get u

Comment: Do the database and the webserver both reside on the same machine?

Comment: ya same pc, ya both reside on same machine

Comment: Are you getting any of your other debug messages? Like your out.println(rs) or out.println("connection...") messages?

Comment: no thats is d main issue why i am not getting any error msg instead msg showing in d web browser is Servlet NewServlet at /WebApplication1. am i missing any jdbc driver connection or what can be d problem??

Comment: Please somebody help me where i am wrong please?

Comment: I expect an expert definitely knows d answer please do comment please

Comment: You don't seem to be sending anything on the HttpResponse, just to the JVM console?

Comment: can you show us the line above and below of : `public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {`

Comment: @AlexPoole hii i have added the code as asked by moskito-x pls hv a look

Comment: i found there is no database connection established from netbeand ide and oracle  bcoz after writing wrong user name and password in connection also i find d same message to be displayed

Comment: What else happens in doPost after the part your showed? Does it call processRequest, or doGet?

Comment: no it does not enter to doPost bcoz i gave wrong database credentials and still no error in database connection coming in browser i think database connection is not established

Comment: @AlexPoole while installing oracle 12 c i selected windows built in account and global database name orcl and after connecting as / as sysdba i created user c##abc identified by abc and granted dba to user c##abc, but sid will be orcl right?

Comment: Focus on the Servlet error before the database connection. Once the Servlet is handling POST properly you'll be able to see if the connection works, and will have an SQLException if it doesn't.

Comment: ok so what is d right code pls??

Comment: @AlexPoole hats off to u man....i got d value xyz now from database.

Comment: @AlexPoole just one doubt can i use sql star plus 8.0 for oracle 12c? i want to see the tables was displayed in sql star plus 8.0

Comment: @Tom - you mean a *very* old version of SQL*Plus from Oracle 8? No, if so, that's too old - use the version from 12c, or the current SQL Developer.

Comment: ya i got it thnx @AlexPoole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `doPost()` method, the `out` you are using is `System.out`, which you have imported (as static). In `processRequest()` you override that with:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()
```

... which is a bit confusing and I'd choose a different variable name. But you aren't doing that in `doPost().` So nothing you write in that method with `println` is doing to the browser via the `HttpServletResponse`, it's just going to the JVM console.

From the code you posted it isn't obvious how `processRequest()` then gets called - which it must be for you to see the output you get. Either you haven't shown a call to `doGet()`/`processRequest()` from that method, or the servlet handling is dropping back to `doGet()` automatically because the response hasn't been initiated, or it's redirecting back to that automatically after an error condition.

Even with a local variable for the `response.getWriter()` you would need to send proper HTML, not just the plain non-tag messages you have now, otherwise you'd just get a blank page.

Comment: now i am getting this error after running browser- java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol